Workflow displays successful deployment message, but the Azure Web App keeps saying that nothing was deployed
This is the pipeline for my Duende IdentityServer application. It's supposed to build then deploy to an Azure Web App:
name: Build and deploy .NET...
on:
  workflow_dispatch
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: IdpBackend
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: src/Web/published
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 8.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: src/Web
jobs:
  build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
  - name: Setup .NET SDK
    uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
    with:
    dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
  - name: Restore
    run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
  - name: Build
    run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
  - name: Test
    run: dotnet test "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --no-build
  - name: Publish
    run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
  - name: Publish Artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: webapp
      path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: build
  steps:
  - name: Download artifact from build job
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: webapp
      path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
  - name: Deploy to Azure WebApp
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    with:
      app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
      publish-profile: ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_PROFILE_IDPBACKEND }}
      package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}

The pipeline is running just fine.
Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
App Service Application URL: https://idpbackend-che0a9fmbhcngdc0.eastus2-01.azurewebsites.net

However, when I try to open the page, I'm getting this error.
Your web app is running and waiting for your content

This is the log from the Azure portal:

I don't know what's going on. I'm using similar pipeline for the API, and it's working just fine.

Can you share your code repo ?

How you are deploying your app?

<system.web>   <applicationPool maxWorkerThreads="50" maxIoThreads="50" /> </system.web> , try this in your web.config file and check once.

the heart beat running for ...which is longer than .. this could be caused by thread pool starvation, for this try to scale up your app and check.

Your web app is running and waiting for your content this is not the error.It is the default page of Azure App Service.Make sure your files are deployed to Azure App Service.


when I try to open the page, I'm getting this error.

It is a default page of Azure App Service (not an error).

Even if your deployment is successful, the app may not find the main page to serve.

Make sure all the files are deployed correctly in the KUDU site/wwwroot folder.


https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/fileManager)


The difference I found in my yml file compared your file is at publish ,path and package .
 - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

- name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

-----------
-----------

- name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'SampleAppOct22'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .


As you mentioned pipeline is working fine for API, the issue may be also with your Identity Server.

Refer this blog on Duende IdentityServer for more details.

the heart beat running for ...which is longer than .. this could be caused by thread pool starvation

One option is to scale up the app service.Also refer this MSDoc for ThreadPool Starvation
